# terraform ecs/CreateCapacityProvider request 500

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-aws-modules

I am getting the following error while trying to create an ECS cluster, at the capacity provider creation phase.

```
2022-01-05T09:15:20.480-0800 [INFO]  plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.70.0_x5: 2022/01/05 09:15:20 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Request ecs/CreateCapacityProvider Details:
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: ecs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.12.31 (+https://www.terraform.io) terraform-provider-aws/3.70.0 (+https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws) aws-sdk-go/1.42.23 (go1.16; darwin; amd64)
Content-Length: 370
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAI2AFJ6MZHHPZ2HTA/20220105/us-east-1/ecs/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=e3f52e06669323c64df6ca485fcb7fae41c6941237fb5dbb0ba6e63478a6eb28
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Date: 20220105T171520Z
X-Amz-Target: AmazonEC2ContainerServiceV20141113.CreateCapacityProvider
Accept-Encoding: gzip

{"autoScalingGroupProvider":{"autoScalingGroupArn":"arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:009710336282:autoScalingGroup:2a7b4cd4-919c-4f59-b33d-bc9486033e17:autoScalingGroupName/terraform-20220105170805411900000007","managedScaling":{"maximumScalingStepSize":1000,"minimumScalingStepSize":1,"status":"ENABLED","targetCapacity":80}},"name":"app-client-capacity-provider"}
-----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2022-01-05T09:15:20.479-0800
2022/01/05 09:15:20 [TRACE] dag/walk: vertex "aws_appautoscaling_policy.ecs_service_policy_scaling" is waiting for "aws_appautoscaling_target.ecs_service_target"
2022-01-05T09:15:21.075-0800 [INFO]  plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.70.0_x5: 2022/01/05 09:15:21 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response ecs/CreateCapacityProvider Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 500
Connection: close
Content-Length: 85
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
Date: Wed, 05 Jan 2022 17:15:20 GMT
X-Amzn-Requestid: 67bc83ad-103a-451d-baf5-4697df2e44cb


-----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2022-01-05T09:15:21.075-0800
2022-01-05T09:15:21.075-0800 [INFO]  plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v3.70.0_x5: 2022/01/05 09:15:21 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] {"__type":"ServerException","message":"Service Unavailable. Please try again later."}: timestamp=2022-01-05T09:15:21.075-0800
```

no details about the error, any idea what might be wrong here?

here is a snippet from my terraform for capacity provider:

```
... (other stuff like ASG launch template etc)

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "cluster-asg" {
  desired_capacity = 3
  min_size = 3
  max_size = 50
  availability_zones = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]

  launch_template { 
    id = aws_launch_template.as_launch_template.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
    value               = true
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}


resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "capacity_provider" {
  name = "app-client-capacity-provider"

  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn         = aws_autoscaling_group.cluster-asg.arn

    managed_scaling {
      instance_warmup_period    = 120
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 1000
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 80
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "app-client" # Naming the cluster
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.capacity_provider.name]
}
```

Comment: I got this after 55 mins of `Still Creating ...`: `error creating ECS Capacity Provider (name-of-cp): ServerException: Service Unavailable. Please try again later.` Your solution solved my problem.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, but using CDK to generate a CloudFormation template. This appears to be related to ECS itself, and I had to resolve it by creating the capacity provider in a second run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this by creating the cluster without capacity provider first then modifying it to have one.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was related to Terraform. I encountered the same issue with CDK and CloudFormation. The first time I resolved it by creating the stack without the Capacity Provider (and its dependencies) and then re-running with it added.

CodePipeline is being used to deploy to a new environment, and commenting out resources and then re-enabling them is not ideal.

I encountered it again for another project, and fixed it by using a signal to cause CloudFormation to wait until the EC2 instances in the AutoScalingGroup were running.

Our projects use CodeDeploy and not `AWS::CloudFormation::Init`, so `cfn-init` isn't invoked.

```
const userData = UserData.forLinux();
// Signal to CloudFormation that the instance is up
userData.addCommands(
  'PS4="$(date -u +"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ") [INFO] "',
  'set -x', // echo everything
  '(',
  'yum install -y aws-cfn-bootstrap',
  `/opt/aws/bin/cfn-signal -e 0 --stack ${this.stack.stackName} --resource ${this.namespace}AutoScalingGroup --region ${awsRegion}`,
  '{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null',
  ') |& tee --append /var/log/ecs/user-data.log'
);
```

The AutoScalingGroup logicalId is overridden using a namespace shared by all resources managed by the CloudFormation stack (eg. MyProjectProdUsEast1). This way the UserData can reference the resource in the `cfn-signal` command (see [this issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/1413)).

```
const autoScalingGroupId = `${this.namespace}AutoScalingGroup`;
const autoScalingGroup = new AutoScalingGroup(this.stack, autoScalingGroupId, {
  ...,  // attributes for the AutoScalingGroup
  userData,
  signals: Signals.waitForAll({
    timeout: Duration.minutes(5),
  }),
});
const cfnAsg = autoScalingGroup.node.defaultChild as CfnAutoScalingGroup;
cfnAsg.overrideLogicalId(autoScalingGroupId);
cfnAsg.autoScalingGroupName = autoScalingGroupId;
```

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-signal.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup.html#signals